# Optimizing window function on postgres (keeping n recent records per account)

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I am new to window function on postgres.  And I am finding its performance pretty slow.  I am curious if I am doing this the right way or if there is a more performant apporach (perhaps building a temp table or using a CTE)

The objective of this statement is to only keep the most recent 100 jobs per account.

```sql
delete
from job_info using (select id, row_number() over (partition by "accountId" order by "completedTime" desc) as rn
                     from job_info) oldest
where job_info.id = oldest.id
  and job_info.type = 'PixelJobInfo'
  and rn > 100;
```

my explain:

```
Delete on job_info  (cost=80321.91..114235.90 rows=111145 width=46)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=80321.91..114235.90 rows=111145 width=46)
        Hash Cond: (job_info.id = oldest.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on job_info  (cost=0.00..26558.16 rows=333433 width=22)
              Filter: ((type)::text = 'PixelJobInfo'::text)
        ->  Hash  (cost=77846.19..77846.19 rows=111178 width=56)
              ->  Subquery Scan on oldest  (cost=67006.36..77846.19 rows=111178 width=56)
                    Filter: (oldest.rn > 100)
                    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=67006.36..73677.02 rows=333533 width=48)
                          ->  Sort  (cost=67006.36..67840.20 rows=333533 width=40)
"                                Sort Key: job_info_1.""accountId"", job_info_1.""completedTime"" DESC"
                                ->  Seq Scan on job_info job_info_1  (cost=0.00..25724.33 rows=333533 width=40)
```

Right now with 300k rows, this is taking 15+ minutes (and still running.  Adding a compound index on account,completedTime also seems to have very little effect

I expect I am doing something structurally wrong.

Would love any advice this community has.

Thanks!

---

Note: there is a child table that has a cascade delete FK reln to this table, and a self-reference parent-child reln

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  I find it strange that the `delete` is filtering on columns not used in the subquery.

Comment: Does the *child table* have an index on the FK-column(s) ?

Comment: The source of the ids to be deleted is unlikely to matter.  It is the number of deletes, both in this table and cascading ones, that is probably driving the performance.

Comment: OMG @wildplasser -- I bet that is it.  It has the fk but not the index!  Doh.  Let me add that

Comment: Note: even with that new index on the child table -- it is still slow.  So @jjanes i guess it might be the number of deletes.  is there a better approach I should be taking

Comment: Did it get *any* faster when you added the index?